# Select one property from multiple expanded properties

Tags: powershell

Below is a script which is using expand property on `get-childitem`

`Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | select  dnsnamelist`

gives me output like below

```
DnsNameList                  
-----------                  
{localhost}
```

so i used expand property to expand it

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | select -ExpandProperty dnsnamelist -Property notafter
```

Which gives me output like below

```
NotAfter             Punycode                    Unicode                    
--------             --------                    -------                    
5/24/2023 5:30:00 AM localhost                   localhost
```

So i need only one property,either unicode or punycode,so below is what i did

```
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | 
select -ExpandProperty dnsnamelist -Property notafter | 
Select-Object -ExcludeProperty punycode
```

But this still gives me unicode and puny code both,how to get only one..

My last pipeline has asked to exclude punycode property,why this doesnt work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As you've discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018703/45375), **in *Windows PowerShell* `-ExcludeProperty` only takes effect if a `-Property` argument such as `*` is also provided** to `Select-Object`. (The first *positional* argument, `*` in the example, implicitly binds to the `-Property` parameter).

While this **behavior is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)**:

> This parameter is effective only when the command also includes the Property parameter.

**there's never been a good reason for it and it should always have been considered a *bug***.

Fortunately, this **problem has been fixed in PowerShell *Core***.

Here's a simple reproduction, trying to exclude property `two` from a custom object with properties `one`, `two`, `three`:

```
($new = ($old = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }) | 
  Select-Object -Exclude two) | Get-Member -Type Properties
```

---

In *Windows PowerShell*, as of v5.1, you see the problematic behavior:

```
   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name  MemberType   Definition 
----  ----------   ---------- 
one   NoteProperty int one=1  
three NoteProperty int three=3
two   NoteProperty int two=2
```

That is, property `two` was NOT excluded.

Additionally, while the type name makes it *seem* like a *new* object was constructed (as one would expect) - given the prefix `Selected.` - that is not actually the case: the very same object is returned, which means that *the input object was unexpectedly modified* (its `.pstypenames` collection), which is another good reason to consider this behavior a bug (`[object]::ReferenceEquals($new, $old)` returns `$True`).

Note, however, that this unwanted modification of the input object only happens with instances of type `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` - instances of other types are simply passed through as-is.

As stated, `*` (`-Property *`) is needed to make the command work as intended.

---

In PowerShell *Core*, as of 6.1.0, the problem has been fixed:

```
   TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name  MemberType   Definition
----  ----------   ----------
one   NoteProperty int one=1
three NoteProperty int three=3
```

That is, property `two` was successfully excluded from the *new* object that was returned (`[object]::ReferenceEquals($new, $old)` returns `$False`)

Answer (score 3):

After writing the question,i figured out an answer,you have to use '`select *` ' in final pipe line ,like below

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | 
select -ExpandProperty dnsnamelist -Property notafter | Select * -ExcludeProperty unicode
```

You also can use expression like below

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | 
select -ExpandProperty dnsnamelist -Property notafter | select notafter,@{Name='SystemName';Expression ={$_.unicode} }
```